Publish Performance test result report cannot parse timestamp with Jmeter result
Publish Performance test result report cannot parse timestamp with Jmeter result. IT throws the following error.
Jmeter script ran using jmx file as below:
jmeter -n -t "C:\xxx\PageLoad\UI_Page_Loading.jmx" -l "C:\TestAutomation\PageLoad\Page_Loading.csv"
Jmeter version: 5.5
Jenkins Plugin: Performance Plugin Version962.v95a_4913d332e
Jenkins version: 2.472
Performance: Failed to parse file 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\xxx\jobs\PERFORMANCE TEST\jobs\xxx\builds\1\performance-reports\JMeterCSV\PageLoading.csv': Cannot parse timestamp: ue. Please, use one of supported formats: [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS, yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse timestamp: ue. Please, use one of supported formats: [yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS, yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss]
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.AbstractParser.initDateFormat(AbstractParser.java:242)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.AbstractParser.parseTimestamp(AbstractParser.java:207)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.JMeterCsvParser.getSample(JMeterCsvParser.java:133)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.JMeterCsvParser.parseCSV(JMeterCsvParser.java:77)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.JMeterCsvParser.parse(JMeterCsvParser.java:66)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.AbstractParser.parse(AbstractParser.java:85)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.locatePerformanceReports(PerformancePublisher.java:481)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.prepareEvaluation(PerformancePublisher.java:424)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.PerformancePublisher.perform(PerformancePublisher.java:395)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:817)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:766)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:710)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1917)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ue"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:1163)
    at PluginClassLoader for performance//hudson.plugins.performance.parsers.AbstractParser.initDateFormat(AbstractParser.java:238)
    ... 19 more```



It looks like your .jtl results file is malformed, incomplete or your Results file configuration differs from what Performance Plugin expects.
The first column should be called timeStamp and by default its value should be the number of milliseconds since beginning of Unix epoch, for example 1724411689136
Instead of this value (or any of supported formats if you amended jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format property you have ue in that column and this is not something the Performance Plugin expects.
So review and eventually revert all your JMeter Properties overrides and ensure that the .jtl results file is complete. It also worth taking a look at jmeter.log file and see whether it contains suspicious entries

There is no customized timestamp configuration made. Same has worked earlier. Let me check.
